# Freeradius Status: Activating, Failure to Start

Tags: 18.04, services, radius

I am new to freeradius.
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
When I try to restart freeradius service as *'service freeradius restart'*, I get
*'Job for freeradius.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status freeradius.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.'*
and then when I look at *journalctl -xe*, I get

```
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Dec 11 16:01:48 servername1 systemd[1]: Stopped FreeRADIUS multi-protocol policy server.
-- Subject: Unit freeradius.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit freeradius.service has finished shutting down.
Dec 11 16:01:48 servername1 systemd[1]: Starting FreeRADIUS multi-protocol policy server...
-- Subject: Unit freeradius.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit freeradius.service has begun starting up.
Dec 11 16:01:48 servername1 gunicorn[5383]:  - - [11/Dec/2020:16:01:48 +0300] "GET /get_active_user_count HTTP/1.0" 200 29 "https://websiteurl.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Dec 11 16:01:48 servername1 gunicorn[5383]:  - - [11/Dec/2020:16:01:48 +0300] "GET /get_active_user_count HTTP/1.0" 200 29 "https://websiteurl.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Dec 11 16:01:48 servername1 systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 11 16:01:48 servername1 systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 11 16:01:48 servername1 systemd[1]: Failed to start FreeRADIUS multi-protocol policy server.
-- Subject: Unit freeradius.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit freeradius.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Dec 11 16:01:48 servername1 gunicorn[5383]:  - - [11/Dec/2020:16:01:48 +0300] "GET /get_download_upload_size HTTP/1.0" 200 60 "https://websiteurl.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like GecDec 11 16:01:48 servername1 gunicorn[5383]:  - - [11/Dec/2020:16:01:48 +0300] "GET /get_active_user_count HTTP/1.0" 200 29 "https://websiteurl.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Dec 11 16:01:49 servername1 microk8s.daemon-containerd[126109]: time="2020-12-11T16:01:49.131916800+0Dec 11 16:13:25 servername1 microk8s.daemon-containerd[126109]: time="2020-12-11T16:13:25.656667400+03:00" level=info msg="ExecSync for \"ded0e9341da992c0dcb052f88119ffaacc8096ce5d66deb35924f697bd68be45\" with command [/bin/calico-node -feDec 11 16:13:25 servername1 microk8s.daemon-containerd[126109]: time="2020-12-11T16:13:25.764586500+03:00" level=info msg="Finish piping \"stdout\" of container exec \"0af2e631aa383ed9fd9ccd515a8dca305618b97ee1e977a29b5d575799f41577\""
Dec 11 16:13:25 servername1 microk8s.daemon-containerd[126109]: time="2020-12-11T16:13:25.764602700+03:00" level=info msg="Finish piping \"stderr\" of container exec \"0af2e631aa383ed9fd9ccd515a8dca305618b97ee1-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit freeradius.service has finished shutting down.
Dec 11 17:16:06 servername1 systemd[1]: Starting FreeRADIUS multi-protocol policy server...
-- Subject: Unit freeradius.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit freeradius.service has begun starting up.
Dec 11 17:16:07 servername1 systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 11 17:16:07 servername1 systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 11 17:16:07 servername1 systemd[1]: Failed to start FreeRADIUS multi-protocol policy server.
-- Subject: Unit freeradius.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit freeradius.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Dec 11 17:16:07 servername1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:12:00:15:5d:62:63:55:08:00 SRC=111.11.111.11 DST=224.0.0.18 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=255 ID=14143 PROTO=112
Dec 11 17:16:09 servername1 microk8s.daemon-containerd[126109]: time="2020-12-11T17:16:09.131796900+03:00" level=info msg="ExecSync for \"ded0e9341da992c0dcb052f88119ffaacc8096ce5d66deb35924f697bd68be45\" with command [/bin/calico-node -felix-ready] and timeout 1 (s)"
Dec 11 17:16:09 servername1 microk8s.daemon-containerd[126109]: time="2020-12-11T17:16:09.244024500+03:00" level=info msg="Finish piping \"stdout\" of container exec \"2cef4de08bccd353cbeedb200fdb00e009b032136ba2b80291c3859911149b88\""
Dec 11 17:16:09 servername1 microk8s.daemon-containerd[126109]: time="2020-12-11T17:16:09.244090600+03:00" level=info msg="Finish piping \"stderr\" of container exec \"2cef4de08bccd353cbeedb200fdb00e009b032136ba2b80291c3859911149b88\""
Dec 11 17:16:09 servername1 microk8s.daemon-containerd[126109]: time="2020-12-11T17:16:09.245730700+03:00" level=info msg="Exec process \"2cef4de08bccd353cbeedb200fdb00e009b032136ba2b80291c3859911149b88\" exits with exit code 0 and error <nil>"
Dec 11 17:16:09 servername1 microk8s.daemon-containerd[126109]: time="2020-12-11T17:16:09.246663300+03:00" level=info msg="ExecSync for \"ded0e9341da992c0dcb052f88119ffaacc8096ce5d66deb35924f697bd68be45\" returns with exit code 0"
Dec 11 17:16:12 servername1 systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 11 17:16:12 servername1 systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 198.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit freeradius.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Dec 11 17:16:12 servername1 systemd[1]: Stopped FreeRADIUS multi-protocol policy server.
-- Subject: Unit freeradius.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit freeradius.service has finished shutting down.
Dec 11 17:16:12 servername1 systemd[1]: Starting FreeRADIUS multi-protocol policy server...
-- Subject: Unit freeradius.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit freeradius.service has begun starting up.
Dec 11 17:16:13 servername1 systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 11 17:16:13 servername1 systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 11 17:16:13 servername1 systemd[1]: Failed to start FreeRADIUS multi-protocol policy server.
-- Subject: Unit freeradius.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit freeradius.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Dec 11 17:16:14 servername1 microk8s.daemon-containerd[126109]: time="2020-12-11T17:16:14.073626000+03:00" level=info msg="ExecSync for \"f2ad79a0a2bc6d3f3ee6f788984bb0070030c0ced9692b217f2a48c0c165cc18\" with command [/usr/bin/check-status -r] and timeout 1 (s)"
```

When I write `sudo freeradius -XC`, I get `Configuration appears to be OK` When I look at status of freeradius with `systemctl status freeradius.service` I get  `Active: activating`
What is the problem here? What can I do to fix it?